# Django print runserver log to a file

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, supervisord

I'm running a django application inside a container using supervisord.

But sometimes i need to view the log to fix some errors and i could'nt find a way to do it.

I tried to add an `stdout_logfile` and `stderr_logfile` but always the err logfile is empty

this is my `supervisor.conf`

```
[supervisord]
loglevel=info
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log

[program:myapp]
command = python3 -u /usr/src/app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
stdout_logfile=/usr/src/app/out.log
stderr_logfile=/usr/src/app/err.log
```

And always the same result, the `out.log` file will contain the lines before the exception happen and the `err.log` won't be created

This is the output that i get when i run docker compose

```
2020-05-13 17:33:44,140 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2020-05-13 17:33:45,144 INFO spawned: 'myapp' with pid 9
2020-05-13 17:33:46,201 INFO success: myapp entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

Comment: why not using gunicorn logs ?

Comment: how can i use it ?

Answer (score 1):

After a big struggling i found the log is being buffered, so the solution is by adding `environment = PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` to the `supervisor.conf` file

my conf file after modification

```
[supervisord]
loglevel=info
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log

[program:myapp]
command = python3 -u /usr/src/app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
environment = PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
stdout_logfile=/usr/src/app/out.log
stderr_logfile=/usr/src/app/err.log
```